# VGA output support for iOS8

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8

My ios8 application needs to integrate VGA output (TV out). I know airplay (iOS8) works fine but Does it still support VGA out (TV out)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no indication in the docs for [`+[UIScreen screens]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScreen_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIScreen/screens) that video out has been dropped in iOS 8, and I've never heard anything to that effect.